# CheckForDetailedUpdate throws "Cannot bind to deployment that is not installed"

Tags: vb.net

I have a 10 second timer checking for updates. I have tried putting "check for updates" in the timer routine. I tried "checking for updates" in a background worker . I have tried async "checking for updates". All throw "Cannot bind to deployment that is not installed". After that, I get a new exception, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". The exception is not necessarily on the 1st check for updates. I have had it run for hours before throwing an exception. After that, it will no longer retrieve an update. If I can't fix the issue, I would like to clear the error. Every 10 seconds out of a hat. I write to a log and/or restart the computer on the main thread.

```
Private Sub tmrAppUpdate_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrAppUpdate.Tick
    If bwAutoUpdates.IsBusy Then Return                             'if updates busy...leave
    bwAutoUpdates.RunWorkerAsync()                                  'check for updates
End Sub

''' <summary>check for and get automatic updates</summary>
Private Sub bwAutoUpdates_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bwAutoUpdates.DoWork
    e.Result = {"ok", ""}                                           'default message

    Try
        Dim updateCheck = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment   'updates
        Dim info = updateCheck.CheckForDetailedUpdate()             'get update info

        If info.UpdateAvailable Then                                'if updates available...
            updateCheck.Update()                                    'download updates
            e.Result = {"restart", "Automatic Update ReStart: "}    'error, error message
        End If                                                      '

    Catch ex As InvalidOperationException                           'error
        e.Result = {"err", "bw ioe: " & ex.Message}                 'error, error message
    Catch ex As DeploymentDownloadException                         'error
        e.Result = {"err", "bw dde: " & ex.Message}                 'error, error message
    Catch ex As InvalidDeploymentException                          'error
        e.Result = {"err", "bw ide: " & ex.Message}                 'error, error message
    Catch ex As TrustNotGrantedException                            'error
        e.Result = {"err", "bw tnge: " & ex.Message}                'error, error message
    Catch ex As Exception                                           'error
        e.Result = {"err", "bw ax: " & ex.Message}                  'error, error message
    End Try                                                         '
End Sub

Private Sub bwAutoUpdates_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bwAutoUpdates.RunWorkerCompleted
    Dim result = CType(e.Result, Array).OfType(Of String)

    If result(1).Length > 0 Then writeLog(result(1))                'write to log!

    Select Case result(0)                                           'what are we going to do?
        Case "ok" : Return                                          'everything ok
        Case "restart" : Application.Restart()                      'restart
        Case "err"                                                  'errors
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this a ClickOnce application? If it is, then use the [ApplicationDeployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment) asynchronous pattern (event-driven), **do not** run it in  BackGroundWorker thread (there's no use for it anyway). Check [IsNetworkDeployed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.isnetworkdeployed) before starting any operation.

Comment: Hi Jimi. It is a ClickOnce app. As mentioned, I used the BW because I tried async and had the same crash issue. I wasn't sure what isNetworkDeployed was for. I did some reading. If you deploy your app as ClickOnce, why do you need to test for it? I added isNetworkDeployed to my code and it still crashes.

Comment: You should not be using background workers, you should be using Tasks. Background workers are pretty much deprecated.

Comment: Tnx MattE. I will look into it. I kind of like Background workers because it makes it EZ to pass your work back to the main thread when you are done.

Comment: Thanks MattE. I learned a lot from Stephen Cleary. I will be moving away from background workers. https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-conclusion.html

Answer (score 1):

The new code is crashing. In poking around, I discovered that this problem has been lurking for 10 years. I don't know why everyone isn't aware of it.

[Microsoft Discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d9183f7e-f5c7-46d0-8bb4-411ad923976c/a-privilege-that-the-service-requires-to-function-properly-does-not-exist-in-the-service-account?forum=winformssetup)

"A privilege that the service requires to function properly does not exist in the service account configuration. You may use the Services Microsoft Management Console (MMC) snap-in (services.msc) and the Local Security Settings MMC snap-in (secpol.msc) to view the service configuration and the account configuration. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070511)"

Answer (score 1):

For the past couple of weeks I have fooled with automatic updates. It has bugs and fails if your app checks for updates often. I have included a link to the full project. You can download it, run it for a couple of days and watch it fail (usually within a couple of hours). When it fails, there seems to be no way to clear the error without a restarting. I have seen reports of this bug going back 10 years. If you find a fix, please let me know. Thanks Sandy

[vb.net AutomaticUpdates](http://www.smarttoolselector.com/debug/AutomaticUpdatesWithEvents%20stack%20overflow.zip)

Answer (score 0):

"Improved solution"

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Deployment.Application
Imports System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment

Public Class frmMain
Private lngUpdateSize As Long = 0
Dim WithEvents ad As ApplicationDeployment

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    lblRev.Text = getRev()
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateApplication()
    If ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed Then        '
        ad = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment       '
        ad.CheckForUpdateAsync()                           'any updates...anyone?
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub adUpdate_CheckForUpdateProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
DeploymentProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles ad.CheckForUpdateProgressChanged
    Const fmt = "{0:F1}K of {1:F1}K downloaded."           'string format
    txtUpdateStatus.Text = String.Format(fmt, e.BytesCompleted / 1024, e.BytesTotal / 
1024)

End Sub

Private Sub adUpdate_CheckForUpdateCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
CheckForUpdateCompletedEventArgs) Handles ad.CheckForUpdateCompleted

    If e.Cancelled Then                                    'if update canceled
        lblMsg.Text = "The update was cancelled."          'display message
        Return                                             'leave
    ElseIf e.Error IsNot Nothing Then                      'if there was an error
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR")                           'display message
        Return                                             'leave
    End If                                                 '

    If e.UpdateAvailable Then                              'if updates available
        lngUpdateSize = e.UpdateSizeBytes                  'get download size
        Dim msg = ""                                       'holder for message

        If Not e.IsUpdateRequired Then                     'update flag set
            msg = "Optional update, Installing now!"       'required message
        Else                                               'optional update
            msg = "Mandatory update, Installing now!"      'optional message
        End If

        lblMsg.Text = msg                                  'display message
        lblMsg.Refresh()                                   'make we see message
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)                       'give chance to see message
        BeginUpdate()                                      '
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BeginUpdate()
    ad = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment           '
    ad.UpdateAsync()                                       'we have them...install em 
now!!!
End Sub

Private Sub adUpdate_UpdateProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
DeploymentProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles ad.UpdateProgressChanged
    Const fmt = "{0:F1}K out of {1:F1}K downloaded - {2:F1}% complete"
    Dim strProgress = String.Format(fmt, e.BytesCompleted / 1024, e.BytesTotal / 1024, 
e.ProgressPercentage)
    txtUpdateStatus.Text = strProgress                     
End Sub

Private Sub adUpdate_UpdateCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
AsyncCompletedEventArgs) Handles ad.UpdateCompleted
    If e.Cancelled Then                                    'if update canceled
        lblMsg.Text = "The update was cancelled."          'display message
        Return                                             'leave
    ElseIf e.Error IsNot Nothing Then                      'if there was an error
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR")                           'display message
        Return                                             'leave
    End If                                                 '

    lblMsg.Text = "App finished updating, Restarting now!" 'display message
    lblMsg.Refresh()                                       'make sure displayed
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)                           'chance to see the message

    Application.Restart()                                  'kill app and restart
End Sub

Private Sub tmrUpdate_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrUpdate.Tick
    UpdateApplication()                                     'time to check for updates
End Sub

Function getRev() As String
    If IsDebug() Then Return "Debug Mode"                   'if debug...return
    Return CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString        'revision
End Function

Function IsDebug() As Boolean
    Return Debugger.IsAttached                              'return debug mode
End Function
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

I created a solution that might help. Basically I look at the modified date of the posted ".application" file. if the date changes, then updates pending. This example is not ftp or http, local only. It prevents CheckForUpdateAsync() from getting hammered (from what I have read is the cause of the problem). Hopes this helps...Sandy

```
Private Sub UpdateApplication()
    If IsNetworkDeployed = False Then Return                'if not deployed...leave
    Dim fName = CurrentDeployment.UpdateLocation.ToString   'full deployment path
    fName = Replace(fName, "file:", Nothing)                'remove
    Dim modD = CStr(File.GetLastWriteTime(fName))           'get file modified
    If modD = My.Settings.fileModified Then Return          'if files match...leave
    My.Settings.fileModified = modD                         'save modified date

    ad = CurrentDeployment                                  'get current deployment
    ad.CheckForUpdateAsync()                                'any updates...anyone?
    writeLog("check for updates")                           'log it!
End Sub
```